# Daisy UI theme is not working while opening in chrome

Tags: reactjs, daisyui

I am a beginner to `ReactJS` and `DaisyUI`, stuck at the theming part of the application.

```
tailwind.config.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  daisyui: {
    themes: ["dark"],
  },
};
```

this is my tailwind config

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-theme="dark" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./src/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <title>LMS</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
    <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is how I am setting the theme using `data-theme="dark"`.

Now, the issue here is while I am opening my site in any other browser like Brave, Edge it's completely working fine but when I open it in Chrome it's not working it shows a light theme in Chrome only.

Any help would be appreciated, **Thanks in advance**

Comment: Did you try opening Chrome in incognito mode? If it works there, it was most probably cached. You can also press F12, long click on the refresh button and select 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'

Comment: @Attila yes, I tried that also